# Module not found: Can't resolve './Header.module.scss' in '/vercel/path0/components/Header'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I got this error when I try to deploy my next application to vercel.
I checked my imports multiple times but I can't see where is the problem.

````sh
Module not found: Can't resolve './Header.module.scss' in '/vercel/path0/components/Header'
```
````

Comment: Please share with us project file system where we can see both of files and how you imports it

Comment: It may be a casing issue, is the file actually named `Header.module.scss` or `header.module.scss`?

Comment: I check multiple times, and I spell the import names correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using git, use the `git config core.ignorecase false` command in your local environment and then commit.